# Can cpp generate a line starting with hash?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, shebang

This c-preprocessor (cpp) input:

```
#define hash #
#define not_hash x
hash
not_hash
```

produces the following output when run through `cpp -P`:

```
 #
x
```

Is there any input to cpp capable of outputting a line that starts with hash as the first character?

Comment: If by CPP you mean a specific standalone implementation of the C preprocessor that gcc used to use a long time ago, then yes, use `-traditional-cpp` flag. If you mean a Platonic idea of the C preprocessor, then the question makes no sense, because at the abstract level the C preprocessor doesn't produce lines at all, it produces a stream of tokens.

Comment: Thank you n. m. could be an AI! that is the answer!!!  -traditional-cpp allows the hash to be generated as the first character of the line.  I added -nostdinc as well so that the hash can be generated as the first line of output.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

n. m. could be an AI answered the question correctly:
"If by CPP you mean a specific standalone implementation of the C preprocessor that gcc used to use a long time ago, then yes, use -traditional-cpp flag. If you mean a Platonic idea of the C preprocessor, then the question makes no sense, because at the abstract level the C preprocessor doesn't produce lines at all, it produces a stream of tokens."